# Stacking Rows of Images Using HTML5/CSS3?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to line images up row by row but for some reason the outcome is not what I want it to be. The only time the images break to a new line is when I fill the page. I tried overflow:hidden, but then when the images expand, they are covered by white space. I can't tell if there is something wrong with my code or if I'm just doing it wrong. I have an poorly drawn image and the the code below.

```css
figure {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  background: white;
  border: 10px solid white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  position: relative;
}
figure img {
  width: 100%;
}
figure:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #666;
}
figure.tall:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transform: scale(3.0);
  -moz-transform: scale(3.0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #666;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<section class="image-gallery">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <figure class="tall" tabindex=1>
      <img src="Gallery/image.jpg" alt="" />
    </figure>
    <figure class="tall" tabindex=2>
      <img src="Gallery/image.jpg" alt="" />
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <figure class="tall" tabindex=3>
      <img src="Gallery/image.jpg" alt="" />
    </figure>

    <figure class="tall" tabindex=4>
      <img src="Gallery/image.jpg" alt="" />
    </figure>
  </div>

</section>
```

[image: Example]

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

P.S. I apologize for my lack of paint skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your code and it should work fine.

```
.wrapper {
    clear:left;
}
```

Because the contents of the wrapper are floated you need to force the subsequent wrapper to clear any content to its left, otherwise they just carry on floating one after the other.

**Update:**

You can also include the text as you stated in your drawing. If you use `<figcaption>` within the `<figure>` it all lines up as expected. I've updated my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hxto41z/2/) to reflect that.

If you want text between the two rows of images, as opposed to being associated with the images above it, you will need use `clear:left;` again to push the text beneath the first row of images.

Comment: EDIT: Add clear left to the text itself? (In my case, an H3.) Also, thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: That's right. I've updated the fiddle to show the <h3> in between the two rows.